# Google AdWords Campaign doesn't show list of Products

Tags: prestashop, google-ads-api, google-shopping

I've searching this issue for about 2 days, so I'm really appreciate your help.

First, I create account at Google Merchants Center and linked it with my site.
The Product Feed is also works well ( I'm using prestashop, so the input methods is "E-Commerce platform imports".
[image]
[image]
As shown in image above, the status is successful.

After that, I create a campaign (max CPC and budget are already created), but here is the result:
[image]

Is there any step that I miss that caused the products doesn't listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Days, I finally found it.

I've just aware that I made a mistake in "Attributes" the value of my site category doesn't being recognized by Google, so I have to create a new one based on the template from google itself.

[image]

After I re-fetch the feed, there are some changes happens. You can compare these below images with above images.

[image]

[image]

And finally... the products show up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, the items, images, and website must adhere 
to all google's rules and policies; individual items
that are searchable does not necessarily indicate
all is well -- always check the main dashboard, the
entire account, and email, for any messages from 
google and check the site's log-files to help verify 
that google has crawled the website and images.

yes, a feed may take 24-72 hours or so to be processed
and all items and images crawled -- before being seen
within the (linked) adwords campaign.

be certain the merchant-center account or sub-account is properly linked.

also, why is an inventory-filter being used?

generally, a filter is created to exclude items --
any items that do not match the filter (exactly)
will be excluded from the campaign.

check the feed file within a browser-window and individual items
within the products-tab to be certain that the items (attributes)
will be able to match the filter, exactly.

also, verify that the remaining products that do fit through the filter
are being included in the defined product-group within the (linked)
adwords-account, by clicking on 'view the full list of products' --
generally, only one campaign is needed but check any other shopping
campaigns and all other product-groups to be certain that the items
are not being filtered or matched elsewhere in the account.

otherwise, google should likely be contacted so that a person can 
look directly into the data-feed, website, images, and both accounts.

Comment: so, when I fetch feed... if there is one image that being rejected, the whole list of products will be hidden by adwords?
If yes, is it only happened for the first time fetch or this will be happen as well in the future even if I have succeeded before?